# How to not include some commands in a log command

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(msg_dump_channel)
    server = ctx.guild.name
    user = ctx.author
    command = ctx.command
    await channel.send('{} used {} in {}'.format(user, command, server))
```

I tried using if "command_name" in ctx.command:
but i get TypeError: argument of type 'Command' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

List the set of commands you want to log and check if the user's command is in that set:

```
commands_to_log = {'command1','command2'}
if ctx.command.name in commands_to_log:
    await channel.send("Your log message")
```